# how to place an image on top of another image while not having the images moving to other position when screen size is changed

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put the lightbulbs in a fixed position above the floor plan, but once I set the position property of the floor plan image to be 'relative', the lightbulb images just couldn't go above the floor plan.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <img src="floorplanff.jpeg" class="background" width="1200px" height="600px">
    <img id="lightbulbbr" src="pic_bulboff.gif" width="45px" height="70px" class="br" >
    <img id="lightbulbfy" src="pic_bulboff.gif" width="45" height="70" class="fy" >
    <img id="lightbulbmr" src="pic_bulboff.gif" width="45" height="70" class="mr" >
    <img id="lightbulbt" src="pic_bulboff.gif" width="30" height="50" class="t" >
    <img id="lightbulbfmngr" src="pic_bulboff.gif" width="45" height="70" class="mngr" >
    <img id="lightbulbar" src="pic_bulboff.gif" width="35" height="65" class="ar" >
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.background {
    size: 80%;
    position: relative;
    left: 8%;
    top: 40%
}

.br {
    position: relative;
    right: 15%;
    top: 85%;
}


.fy {
    position: absolute;
    right: 79.8%;
    top: 34%;
    transform: rotate(90deg)
}

.mr {
    position: absolute;
    right: 57.5%;
    top: 67.5%;
}
```

[my html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gzAB.jpg)

Comment: Your main `<div>` (lets call it `.wrapper`) has to be *relative* and all images inside it need to be *absolute*. Main floorplan image `z-index: 0` and bulbs `z-index: 1` (at least higher than the floorplan). Also, you seem to want to be able to resize the page, this means you need to get rid of the inline fixed size values and create classes using relative (%) values, otherwise you will get a small resized floorplan with huge bulbs.

Answer (score 0):

try `overflow: visible;` on `.background` and parent `div`.
And also I would use position absolute on `.br`

Comment: but wouldn't the lightbulb's position change when screensize is change/minimize? because previously I used absolute for all lightbulbs, and it happened.

Comment: Make parent div with bg image floorplan and positon relative, and then play with the lightbulbs.

Comment: does it work for you?

Comment: unfortunately no, lightbulbs still moves when screen is resized